# Does every 3CNF propositional formula has an equivalent 2CNF propositional formula?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, propositional-logic

Does every 3CNF propositional formula has an **equivalent** 2CNF propositional formula?

Definitions:

3CNF propositional formula is conjunctive normal form propositional formula, which is just conjunction $\land$ of clauses, where each clause is disjunction $\lor$ of at most **3** literals, where each literal is just boolean variable either with or without not $\lnot$ operator/connective.

2CNF propositional formula is conjunctive normal form propositional formula, which is just conjunction $\land$ of clauses, where each clause is disjunction $\lor$ of at most **2** literals, where each literal is just boolean variable either with or without not $\lnot$ operator/connective.

Comment: Does _equivalent_ mean _equisatisfiable_ here?

Comment: @Dmitri Chubarov if propositional formula $A$ is equivalent to propositional formula $B$ then this imply that $A$ is equisatisfiable to $B$ and $B$ is equisatisfiable to $A$, but the converse is false: If $A$ is equisatisfiable to $B$ then not necessarily that $A$ is equivalent to $B$. My question is for **equivalence** but **not** for equisatisfiability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single clause 3CNF:

$\varphi = a\lor b\lor c$

does not have an equivalent 2CNF. Suppose $\psi=\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^m \psi_i$ is an equivalent 2CNF. Let $\psi_i$ be one of its clauses, and assume it involves the variables $a,b$. An assignment which sets $c=1$, but does not satisfy $\psi_i$, satisfies $\varphi$ but not $\psi$, hence they are not equivalent.

Comment: Ah, got confused, it's only possible to make a 2CNF with same amount of positive assignments as for given 3CNF but they won't be equal.

Comment: So Ariel's answer implies that rus9384's comment is wrong then.

Comment: Why would this argument fail when we try to apply it to prove that $a \vee b \vee c \vee d$ does not have an equivalent 3CNF?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov It wouldn't. To be able to express all boolean functions on $k$ variables, you need $k$-variable clauses. The NP completeness of 3SAT has nothing to do with it.